# How to integrate D3.js into Android App

Tags: android, d3.js

All:

Say I have several D3 based Data Viz chart(with a lot of data and user interaction), what I want to do is move them to mobile phone as Android App, I tried mobile browser to run those chart, the result and performance is not that good. So I wonder if there is a way that can run those JS code like native app?

Thanks

Comment: I think you can make an application with https://cordova.apache.org/ from html, css and JS. But it will be not better in performance I think than in a browser. On the other hand, you can generate application for other mobile platforms as well, like IPhone. And you can even access the mobile sensors from JS.

Comment: @Peter Thanks, I do not need any sensor access, just want to make the performance of those D3 charts look good as possible as in Desktop